# Split a string according to flanking characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript lets you split a string according to regular expression. Is it possible to use this functionality to split a string only when the delimiter is flanked by certain characters?

For example, if I want to split the string `12-93` but not `at-13` using the `-` character? Is that possible?

Using a regular expression seems promising, but doing `"12-93".split(/[0-9]-[0-9]/)` yields `["1", "3"]` because the flanking digits are considered to be part of the delimiter.

Can I specify the above split pattern (a dash preceded and followed by a digit) without chopping the flanking digits?

**Other Examples**

`"55,966,575-165,162,787"` should yield `["55,966,575", "165,162,787"]`

`"55,966,575x-165,162,787"` should yield `["55,966,575x-165,162,787"]`

`"sdf55,966,575-165,162,787"` should yield `["sdf55,966,575", "165,162,787"]`

Comment: What about this: `/d{2}-d{2}/` which specifies two digits a dash and two digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two adjacent character sets seems to work.

See example at https://regex101.com/r/uFHMW1/1

`([0-9,a-z]+?[0-9]+)-([0-9]+[0-9,a-z]+)`

Try this (live here https://repl.it/EOOQ/0 ):

```js
var strings = [
"55,966,575-165,162,787",
"55,966,575x-165,162,787",
"sdf55,966,575-165,162,787",
];

var pattern = '^([0-9,a-z]+?[0-9]+)-([0-9]+[0-9,a-z]+)$';
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

var matched = strings.map(function (string) {
 var matches = string.match( regex );
 if (matches) {
  return [matches[1], matches[2]];
 } else {
  return [string];
 }
});

console.log(matched)
```

You can also run the above expression as `split()` like:

`string.split(re).filter( str => str.length )`

where `Array.filter()` is used to get rid of the leading and trailing empty strings created when the RegExp matches your input.

```js
var strings = [
"55,966,575-165,162,787",
"55,966,575x-165,162,787",
"sdf55,966,575-165,162,787",
];
var pattern = '^([0-9,a-z]+?[0-9]+)-([0-9]+[0-9,a-z]+)$';
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

var matched = strings.map( string => string.split(regex).filter( str => str.length ) );

console.log(matched)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `non-capturing` lookahead. You are using a regex that captures all of the characters found, then uses that result as the split character(s).